# Is this the correct way to shift space from one LVM to another?

Tags: rhel, xfs

I need to move 500G from my RHEL 8 XFS home volume to the root volume. Here's what I have now:

[image]

Can someone tell me if this blog post has the correct instructions for doing this?
https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/shrink-xfs-root-lvm/

Then once I shrink the home volume, do I follow the same steps for root giving it a larger disk size?

This isn't my area of expertise so I'm nervous.

Summary:
Reduce size of / on XFS volume

1. Do a full backup
2. Boot to rescue mode
3. Choose Skip to Shell
4. vgchange -ay
5. mkdir /mnt/sysimage/rt
6. mkdir /mnt/sysimage/backup
7. mount /dev/mapper/rhel-root /mnt/sysimage/rt/
8. mount /dev/mapper/rhel-home /mnt/sysimage/backup/
9. xfsdump -l 0 -L "root lv backup" -M "backup" -f /mnt/sysimage/backup/root_backup.img /mnt/sysimage/rt
10. lsof /mnt/sysimage/rt/
11. kill -9
12. umount /mnt/sysimage/rt/
13. lvremove /dev/mapper/rhel-root
14. lvcreate -Zy -L 15G -n root rhel
15. mount /dev/mapper/rhel-root /mnt/sysimage/rt
16. xfsrestore -f /mnt/sysimage/backup/root_backup.img /mnt/sysimage/rt
17. umount /mnt/sysimage/rt/ /mnt/sysimage/backup/
18. exit

Comment: assuming: a) you have taken a full backup before doing this, as mentioned in the post you linked, i.e. not the backup you will be doing as part of the guide, b) you have enough space in your `/home` mount to make the backup that you will be using later (looks like you should) - then there's no reason to fear

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX

Comment: Please summarise the content of the linked resource in your question, so that it still makes sense when the target is unavailable.